# Debugging and stepping into getSystemService() show the wrong line in Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

Stepping into the call:

```
   SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager)   getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
```

Shows the wrong line in debugger, why is this?

[image]

I have downloaded the source and set the following:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.android.searchabledict"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 21
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}
```

My attached Android API is: Android API 21 Platform

It works for this call:

```
  UriMatcher matcher =  new UriMatcher(UriMatcher.NO_MATCH);
```

Comment: You probably `added/removed` any `line of code` while you were in `Debugging` mode. Just stop `Debugging` and try again

Comment: One call works but the other not (see post above). But when I changed from launching AVD API 22 to AVD API 21 it works!?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because the SDK you running on is not the target SDK you working with. So the debugging metadata from the running process is not synchronised with the source code.

Try changing the target SDK to the one on the device you running on and make sure you have the right version of the sources.

Comment: My targetSdkVersion is 21 and my library is 21?. I found out that if I start AVD with API 21 it works. Is that what you mean (see my comment above)?

Comment: Exactly, the target SDK and the debugged device should be with the same SDK version.

Comment: OK. UriMatcher call worked though. Seems some work but not all. Be interesting to know in more detail why it is like this.

Comment: As I said- the JVM passing debugging metadata to the editor, think of something like class name and line. So when the sdk version not synced- the editor will jump to wrong position in the source code (because the source code might changed from one version to the next)

Comment: It would be good with a warning in the Android Studio. If the Studio SDK is not the same as JVM and SDK in AVD.